# Trouble setting up IIS for ASP

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

- Windows 7 Ultimate
- IIS7

At first I enabled all settings in IIS, the default page of IIS could be viewed but when I tried to view pages in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWeb`, I used to get a 404 error.

Then I tried:

- ASP
- ISAPI extensions
- Request filtering

It didn't show me the default IIS page even. Then I tried:

- ASP
- ASP.NET
- ISAPI Extensions
- Default document
- Static content
- Request filtering

It showed me the default page but when I tried to view files in the directory, Chrome said that the link appears to be broken. At present my settings are:

- IIS management console
- .net extensibility
- asp
- asp.net
- cgi
- isapi extensions
- isapi filters
- server-side includes
- default document
- static content
- request filtering

Still, I am getting the "link broken" message.

Oh, and I am using Dreamweaver CS5 and when I preview the ASP page from Dreamweaver it asks me if I would like to specify a testing server. I choose No as I am new to this and not aware of how to specify a server. Is that the problem?

Comment: Thankfully we moved to ASP.NET for IIS7; all of our old Classic ASP page servers run on 2003 and earlier!  I did [find this](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2007/05/21/tips-for-classic-asp-developers-on-iis7.aspx) if it's any use.

Answer (score 0):

This is the official site for your problem:
http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8

The first entry is probably what you need.

I recently set up ASP on IIS8 by simply installing the server features you listed first (ASP and ISAPI Extensions). Maybe you have another problem, like a wrongly setup website in IIS. You could enter a simple default.asp or maybe you should try a `iisreset` and check that some static file is available where you expect the asp files to work.